# MySQL remove duplicates in one column, leaving smallest and greatest values based on second column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table which contains two columns:

```
count | when
101   | 10:11
101   | 10:12
102   | 10:13
102   | 10:14
102   | 10:15
102   | 10:16
103   | 10:17
105   | 10:18
105   | 10:19
105   | 10:20
```

I need to remove all the duplicate `count` entries, but leave two rows with the smallest and largest `when` value:

```
count | when
101   | 10:11
101   | 10:12
102   | 10:13 _ removed 2 rows
102   | 10:16
103   | 10:17
105   | 10:18 _ removed 1 row
105   | 10:20
```

This is in order to minimize the table size, which is mainly used for statistical purpose, hence points with the same Y-axis values are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports `join` syntax for the `delete` command.

Using this syntax, you can set up a filter for the appropriate records to delete:

```
delete t
    from yourtable t join
         (select count, min(when) as minwhen, max(when() as maxwhen
          from yourtable
          group by count
         ) tokeep
         on t.count = tokeep.count and (t.when > tokeep.minwhen and t.when < tokeep.maxwhen);
```